# Single-row subquery returns more than one row - Issue in table conversion in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a issue related to Snowflake. When I run the below query, I do get 'Single-row subquery returns more than one row.'

Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue?

Below is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT J.JOB_ID , J.ACCEPTED_DATE ,
(SELECT DOCUMENT_ID FROM (SELECT DD.DOCUMENT_ID ,row_number() over (partition by DD.DOCUMENT_ID order by DD.DOCUMENT_ID ) as row_number 
FROM SFG.RCM_JOB_INDUSTRY DD
LEFT JOIN USERS_L.JOB_MASTER J ON DD.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID) WHERE row_number=1) AS DOCUMENT_ID,
(SELECT U.USERNAME FROM SFL.RCS_USER U LEFT JOIN SMW.RCS_STATUS RS ON RS.USER_ID = U.USER_ID) AS REPAIRED_BY
FROM USERS_L.JOB_MASTER J
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 subqueries, and I suspect the second one causing the issue:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT J.JOB_ID,
    J.ACCEPTED_DATE,
    (
        SELECT
            DOCUMENT_ID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    DD.DOCUMENT_ID,
                    row_number() over (
                        partition by DD.DOCUMENT_ID
                        order by
                            DD.DOCUMENT_ID
                    ) as row_number
                FROM
                    SFG.RCM_JOB_INDUSTRY DD
                    LEFT JOIN USERS_L.JOB_MASTER J ON DD.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID
            )
        WHERE
            row_number = 1
    ) AS DOCUMENT_ID,
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 U.USERNAME
        FROM
            SFL.RCS_USER U
            LEFT JOIN SMW.RCS_STATUS RS ON RS.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
    ) AS REPAIRED_BY
FROM
    USERS_L.JOB_MASTER J
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/top_n.html